# EM-18 RFID module not reading Card ID

Tags: arduino-mega, rfid

I am using EM-18 Rfid module with Arduino mega the problem is that when i swipe the card for reading the card ID nothing will shown in serial monitor.Code given below.EM-18 connection diagram is given in attachments.

```
int count = 0;
    char card_no[12];
    void setup()
    {
       Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop()
    {
       if(Serial.available())
       {
          count = 0;
          while(Serial.available() && count < 12)
          {
             card_no[count] = Serial.read();
             count++;
             delay(5);
          }
          Serial.print(card_no);
       }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: your code is unnecessarily complex .... furthermore,  you do not print anything until 12 characters have been received .... that is "shooting yourself in the foot" .... print the characters as they arrive ... that means, get rid of the `while` block .... reduce the code to `if serial data is available, then get serial data and print it`

Comment: Is this ok?                                                                                            
 int count = 0;
    char card_no[12];
    void setup()
    {
       Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop()
    {
       if(Serial.available())
       {
          
             card_no = Serial.read();
          
          Serial.print(card_no);
       }
    }